# "dylib loader is 6.x == 0" error when deploying to a jailbroken iPhone running 5.1.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, deployment, dylib

> XCODE 4.5.1   iPhone 4s 5.1.1 (9B206)

I have all of the iOS development certificates and provisioning profiles and the app works. It works fine when deploying to another iPhone (same model and version etc, also jailbroken). Just not to my iPhone.

When "build and running" it builds fine and put the app on the iPhone just fine. But when running it opens and closes with the console-message

> dylib loader is 6.0 == 0

I can click the app later on and it works just fine, so it crashes when using the debugger I am assuming (LLDB).

As said the device is jailbroken. To build and deploy works fine when I am in "safe mode" so I am assuming I have some package (cydia) installed which is interfering with the debugger?

I cannot find anything with google regarding

> dylib loader is ...

Worst case scenario I'll have to disable packages one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*PhotoAlbumsPlus* is the culprit, i have no idea why but once i disabled it temporarily in `SBSettings` it worked again, but i can't be disabling that every time I want to debug in xcode time to email the author and tell him to fix it!!

to find the culprit i did the following in the terminal

```
 ls > LIST in my the DynamicLibraries folder
```

and then

```
( while read line; do strings $line | grep "loader" ; echo $line ; done ) < LIST
```

the dylib echoed after dylib loader is `6.x == %d` turned out to be the culprit. not exactly an elegant solution but it helped narrow it down!

EDIT:

a much more elegant way to do it (while outside of the DynamicLibraries folder)

```
grep "dylib loader" DynamicLibraries -r
```

Comment: That's cool. I do have PhotoAlbumsPlus so I guess that's somewhat of an confirmation. I'll set it to the answer, thanks.